# Limitations of wine

Tags: wine, winetricks

Can I run any windows application using wine or is it limited to only small applications?

I'm asking this because, it didn't run unity 3D

Comment: wine gets tricky once you need directx and system dlls - performance wise not even close to virtualbox. May also see playonlinux which simplifies the wine setup and version mgmt. Wine might be a good option commandline applications.

Comment: WINE is kind of useless. Best to install Virtualbox with a Windows OS guest. Also, WINE doesn't have anything to do with Unity 3D.

Comment: "WINE is kind of useless." No, the version in the Ubuntu repos is (Wine 1.6 is ancient), but when using the latest version, it often works quite well.

Comment: @OP try installing the latest version from here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

It isn't dependent on the size of the app. Nor can you totally go by published comments of users, though that's a good start. A lot of things don't work out of the box but can be made to with a lot of tinkering with Wine settings. And what worked a year ago may not today and vice versa. The only absolute answer:

```
while [ user is not out of patience ]; do
    Fiddle some more with wine settings
    Try again
done
```

But this solution has been known to lead to baldness from auto-hair-pulling, loud cussing, and the appearance of men in white coats, who calmly tell you that you've had too much wine.

Comment: Love your answer

Answer (score 1):

No, `wine` has its limitations and can not run every Windows application very well or at all.

You can check the full list of supported apps, rated by user voting on how well they perform on the [Wine Application Database (AppDB)](https://appdb.winehq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

`wine` can't run every Windows applications, if you want to install and run Windows apps on the Linux, [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) is a good choice. It implements many prerequiste packages for the Windows apps, so install from PlayOnLinux can make the install process much easier. But still not all the Windows apps can't be installed on Linux, some of them are under testing.